# Added new custom document type extension not working

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am developing a document-based app, and I want to add a new custom document type to the exported types identifier. Currently, there is already one document type called "asblt" in the app. I have added the new document type "AS" in the info.plist file, but when I open the document browser, it is unable to display documents of the new document type. How can I resolve this issue and make the new document type "AS" visible in the document browser alongside the existing "asblt" document type?
Screen short and source code is attached below:
[image]

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.text</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Sketch File</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>ic_launcher.png</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.ken.asbuiltsketch.asblt</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>asblt</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>New Sketch File</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.ken.asbuilt-sketch.as</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>as</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```